# Read dates when its in quotes

Tags: sas

How to read the dates with quotes. I tried without quotes, its working fine.

How to chance the sysfunc according to it.

```
%let date='2017-01-01'; 
%let et=%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(inputn(&date.,yymmdd10.)),2,s),yymmn6.);
%put   &et.;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dequote` to remove the quotation marks:

```
%let date='2017-01-01'; 
%let et=%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(inputn(%sysfunc(dequote(&date.)),yymmdd10.)),2,s),yymmn6.);
%put   &et.;
```

Comment: `Dequote` is spot on, a shorter version `et= %sysfunc(dequote(&date.))` will also create `2017-01-01`